# How does Bash know when to do Filename Expansion?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Typing `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/`, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> causes filename expansion, which lists all files in `~/.ssh`.

Typing `ssh-copy-id` without the `-i` flag, then <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't cause file expansion.

Typing `ssh-copy-id -x`, <kbd>Spacebard</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>(note that `-x` is an invalid flag) also does not lead to file expansion.

How does Bash "know" to do file expansion after typing `-i`? Does the program `ssh-copy-id` have to be programmed in a way to let Bash know to do it? I read this page and others on filename expansion but could not find an answer for my question:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html

Bash version:
`GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tab-completion is different from filename expansion.

**[Tab-completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Completion.html)** is a native feature of Bash GNU Readline for interactive
Bash sessions. For example, it completes variables (try `echo $SH<TAB>`) and
also commands arguments with file names.

Additionally, if `bash-completion` package is installed, the
completion becomes more intelligent for the commands comprised in
in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions`, one of which is
`ssh-copy-id`. Since the `-i` flag for `ssh-copy-id` requires a file,
it tab-completes files. Without `-i`, there does not make sense to supply
a file, so no completion is performed.

Again, that is only true for commands in the `completions` directory.
If you have a `foobar` command that does not accept a file as an
argument, Bash will still complete with files because `bash-completion`
has no idea of `foobar`.

On the other hand, **filename expansion** is a POSIX shell behavior. It occurs
regardless of whether the shell is interactive or not. Example: `ssh-copy-id -x *` causes `*` to expand to all files in the current directory, the
command wanting them or not.

Comment: Tab-completion itself (mostly of filenames) is a feature of Bash proper. The per-utility configurations that try to guess what you want to tab-complete are part of `bash-completion`.

Comment: Filename expansion is synonymous with globbing.   See https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html et al.  It is not just a 'POSIX shell behavior'; globbing has been around since at least Unix V6.

Comment: @fpmurphy I only won't incorporate it in my answer because it is irrelevant for the purposes of the question if that originates in Bash, POSIX standard or Unix V6, but it is always nice to have a historical background, thanks for the comment.